# I have created a custom billing object and a trigger for billing if my opportunity is 'Clsoed-Won'

Tags: apex, trigger

I have made the below trigger but whenever i try to create or edit some opportunity, it is showing an error

```
trigger CreateBilling on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {
    Id OppId;
    List<Opportunity> oppList;
    List<Account> wt;
    Boolean oldOppIsWon;
    Boolean newOppIsWon;
     Opportunity oldOpp;
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Opportunity oppty : trigger.new){
           OppId = oppty.Id;
            newOppIsWon = oppty.StageName.equals('Closed Won');
            oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(oppty.Id);
            oldOppIsWon = oldOpp.StageName.equals('Closed Won');
            }

        }
      if ((!oldOppIsWon && newOppIsWon)) {
         oppList = [Select id,amount,AccountId,Billing_Mode__c,lastmodifieddate,stagename from Opportunity where id =: OppId limit 1];
        system.debug('1');
        if(oppList.size() > 0)   {
            system.debug('11');
         wt = [select id,wholesaler__c from Account where id=: oppList[0].AccountId limit 1];
            system.debug('111');
        }
        if(wt.size()>0 && oppList.size() > 0){
            system.debug('14');
        Billing__c billrec = new Billing__c();
        billrec.Billed_Amount__c =oppList[0].amount;
        billrec.Account__c= oppList[0].AccountId;
        billrec.Opportunity__c = oppList[0].id;
        billrec.Wholesaler__c = wt[0].wholesaler__c;
        billrec.Payment_Mode__c = oppList[0].Billing_Mode__c;
        billrec.Billing_Date__c = oppList[0].lastmodifiedDate.Date();   

            insert billrec;
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please FORMAT code part so that we can see what is at line 12.

Comment: you have trigger on INSERT, in this case Trigger.oldMap will be empty.
Can you try once running above code for update only. Remove after insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger is firing at before Insert and at this stage **oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(oppty.Id);** will have a null value. Refer this link below. It has almost the same functionality of trigger which you are trying to achieve.

http://www.sfdc99.com/2014/02/25/comparing-old-and-new-values-in-a-trigger/

Hope this helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Divi add the an if condition above `oldOppIsWon = oldOpp.StageName.equals('Closed Won');`
change your code like this

```
if(Trigger.oldMap.get(oppty.Id) != null){
    oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(oppty.Id);
    oldOppIsWon = oldOpp.StageName.equals('Closed Won');}
```

or

```
 if(isUpdate){
    oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(oppty.Id);
    oldOppIsWon = oldOpp.StageName.equals('Closed Won');}
```

This may help you to get through.

Comment: Hey Anu, I am still getting the same error after adding the above condition

Comment: Hey @DiviAgarwall I have updated my code try this - The issue is because the code get executed on after insert. And in after insert you dont have any value in  Trigger.oldMap.

Comment: Hey Anu, I tried this but it still shows the same error while creating/editing an opportunity.